# How to convert cURL request to axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to use the below `cURL` command with the `axios`. How I can do that?

`curl -XPOST -d 'url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F' 'https://goolnk.com/api/v1/shorten'`

I have tried in this way but seems to be incorrect:

```
axios.post("https://goolnk.com/api/v1/shorten", {
   url: "https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F"
}).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost made it, but `url` key should just be a link string, without any special symbols.

```
axios
  .post('https://goolnk.com/api/v1/shorten', { url: 'https://google.com' })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
  });
```

Please, don't post code as images in the future, instead insert it as code block in the text.